# How to put database from Microsoft SQL server to phpMyadmin on local host

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I already have a database in Mcrosoft SQL Server, now I want to put this database to phpMyadmin, what should I do?

Comment: do need to connect mssql server?

Comment: Since phpMyAdmin appears to be for MySQL then you need to migrate your SQL Server database to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using SQL database with PHP. Its quite easy and using mssql commands you can connect to SQL Server database

Comment: i don't want to create this database on phpmyadmin again, it has lot of tables and data

Comment: Then better configure your SQL database with the php.. and use the SQL database table

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you want to do. You can use Import-Export Wizard of MS SQL server. Or you can try my tool wjISQL available at http://www.queper.in.